# Appcompat Spinner inside RecycleView without arrow

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

I'm stuck trying to add a spinner to recycle view.

There are two problems.

1. there is no focus when using
   `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

   the spinner does not open.I have tried using

> android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

but still doesn't work.

2. When i remove`android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`
   it works but there is an default arrow that i dont want to have.

my question is what is the right way to focus on the spinner and remove the arrow.

thank you.

Comment: Post screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
<style parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner" name="SpinnerwithNoArrow">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/edit_text</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, tnx for your help guys.

finally, i have figured it out and instead of spinner I just used ListPopupWindow.